# Get nested object value with preserving the type

Tags: typescript

I need the function which can return the value by keys path divided by dots and the output value should have the correct type

```
interface MyConfigI {
  port: number,
  host: string,
  aws: {
    isEnabled: boolean,
    secret: string,
    s3: {
      bucket: string
    }
  }
}

const config: MyConfigI = {
  port: 555,
  host: 'localhost',
  aws: {
    isEnabled: true,
    secret: 'some-secret',
    s3: {
      bucket: 'my-bucket'
    }
  }
}

const s3 = getConfigValue(config, 'aws.s3') // s3: { bucket: string } = { bucket: 'my-bucket'}
const bucket = getConfigValue(config, 'aws.s3.bucket') // s3bucket: string  = 'my-bucket'
```

It is not a problem at all to return the value, the problem is to preserve type of returning value.

How to achieve it?
There are a lot of npm modules that can get to needed value, but the result type is any or unknown

Comment: Use `as const satisfies MyConfigI` and make `MyConfigI` readonly.